# Copy paste to excel from wijmo flexgrid with thousand seperator

Tags: excel, angular, copy-paste, wijmo

I'm using the wijmo flexgrid in an angular 2 application. My flexgrid cells are formated with " " as the thousand separator. When i copy a row from the grid and paste it into excel it is not recognized as a number.

For example 1 000 000 is interepted as text in excel. Any recomendations for how to handle this?

Comment: I guess you can either force cell format in Excel or provide additional helpers to the app (copy row/table to clipboard, export CSV).

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle standard keydown event for FlexGrid and convert copied data to proper number format and set to Clipboard using Wijmo Clipboard class copy method. Please refer to the following code snippet and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkgupta911/6GB66/1103/):

```
grid.hostElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // copy: ctrl+c or ctrl+Insert
  if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 67 || e.keyCode == 45)) {
    var _sel= grid.selection,
                _item= grid.getCellData(_sel.row,_sel.col,true),
                _result;
        var _col= grid.columns[_sel.col];
        if(_col.dataType==wijmo.DataType.Number){
          _result = _item.toString().replace(/ /gi, function (x) {
             return "";
          });          
        }
    wijmo.Clipboard.copy(_result);
    return;
  }
});
```

~Manish Kumar Gupta